# Ionic application error: array.push() is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, ionic-framework

I created an application where I have controller and factory. I have an array inside of the factory where I want to push id of the element to this array. However, when I am trying to push element to array I got an error that

> "favorites.push is not a function"

Below you can find my controller and factory. Thank you for reading:
**Factory:**

```
.factory('favoriteFactory',['$resource', 'baseURL','$localStorage', function ($resource, baseURL, $localStorage) {
            var favFac = {};
            var favorites = $localStorage.get('favorites', []);
          favFac.addFavorites = function (index) {
            for(var i=0; i<favorites.length; i++){
              if(favorites[i].id == index)
                return
            }
              favorites.push({id: index});
              $localStorage.storeObject('favorites',favorites)
          }
          favFac.deleteFromFavorites = function (index) {
            for (var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
              if (favorites[i].id == index) {
                favorites.splice(i, 1);
              }
            }
            $localStorage.storeObject('favorites', favorites)
          };

          favFac.getFavorites = function () {
            return $localStorage.getObject('favorites',[]);
          };
          return favFac
        }])
```

**Controller:**

```
    .controller('MenuController', ['$scope', 'menuFactory', 'favoriteFactory','baseURL', '$ionicListDelegate', 'dishes', '$localStorage',
         function($scope, menuFactory,favoriteFactory, baseURL, $ionicListDelegate, dishes, $localStorage) {


        $scope.baseURL = baseURL;
        $scope.tab = 1;
        $scope.filtText = '';
        $scope.showDetails = false;
        $scope.showMenu = true;
        $scope.message = "Loading ...";
        $scope.addFavorite = function (index) {
          console.log("index:" +index);
          favoriteFactory.addFavorites(index);
          $ionicListDelegate.closeOptionButtons();

        };
        $scope.dishes = dishes;

            $scope.select = function(setTab) {
              $scope.tab = setTab;

              if (setTab === 2) {
                $scope.filtText = "appetizer";
              }
              else if (setTab === 3) {
                $scope.filtText = "mains";
              }
              else if (setTab === 4) {
                $scope.filtText = "dessert";
              }
              else {
                $scope.filtText = "";
              }
                };
   $scope.isSelected = function (checkTab) {
      return ($scope.tab === checkTab);
    };

    $scope.toggleDetails = function() {
      $scope.showDetails = !$scope.showDetails;
    };
  }])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using `ngStorage`. The get method does not have a second parameter. Therefore, your attempt at returning a default value of `[]`(empty array) is simply returning `undefined` and then you are attempting to push to `undefined` and not to an array.

The source code for `ngStorage` shows no second parameter for `get`:
https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage/blob/master/ngStorage.js

So this line:

```
var favorites = $localStorage.get('favorites', []);
```

Should be this:

```
var favorites = $localStorage.get('favorites') || [];
```

Comment: Thank you for the response by default it can take two parameters. The second is the default value of that which you can provide. Problem is whatever I am changing that I got the same error. even when I am creating simple array.

Comment: This is second part from my code where I created the same things get: function (key,defaultValue) {
            return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
          },

Comment: I know I am talking about my own function which I just shared that. It is doing the same things and I send to that default value. var favorites = $localStorage.get('favorites') || [];

Comment: Perhaps you have stored, already, a value in local storage which matches your key, that is not an array.

Comment: Also, what is the difference between `get` and `getObject` ?

Comment: I use getObject to parse json value.

Comment: However you are implementing `$localStorage` does not change the fact that `var favorites = $localStorage.get('favorites', []);` is not returning an array.

Comment: Yes, you were right. So I found the bug. That value was kept in local storage.  So whatever I have done it always returned me the error. The value already was in local storage. So just I cleaned that and it worked. ) Thanks again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142015/discussion-between-agil-yolchuyev-and-joelcdoyle).