# Ionic Cordova ngstorage error

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am quite new in Ionic Cordova IOS and Android development. I have some problems with my application. My first question by default where is location (in Mac) of the log files in Cordova IoS and Android applications? Secondly I use `ngstorage` in my application. I have an array where I must push my data to that array. Each time after the quitting my application, when I try to access to that array I got an error that `Push method is not a function`. However after the cleaning the storage from browser everything become the normal. The same things repeated every time when I push new element to the array. But it shows me that new element in list. Below is my storage code. But I think there is no strange something here:

```
.factory('$localStorage',['$window', function ($window) {
        return {
          store: function(key, value) {
            $window.localStorage[key] = value;
          },
          get: function (key, defaultValue) {
            return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
          },
          storeObject: function (key, value) {
            $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
          },
          getObject: function (key, defaultValue) {
            return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue)
          }
        }
```

Also here is my second question which is part of this application for push method:
[Ionic application error: array.push() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459913/ionic-application-error-array-push-is-not-a-function/43460086#43460086)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localStorage and sessionStorage done right for AngularJS.
[Github](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)